# ASP.NET: How can I set up my resources where I can use the same location for Development site and the Production version?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, resources, web

I currently have my resources (images) in ...

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\images
```

I also have the images in the same location on my production server.  How can I set it up so that I don't have to constantly sync up the folders?  Seems like an easy thing but I'm not sure...

Any other information let me know and I will provide.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you include them in your web project? That way when you deploy the web project the images are included by default :)

Comment: Well I have a bunch of pictures and if I try to do what you say I'm thinking it's going to redeploy 3GBs of pictures possibly every time I go to publish or at least dramatically slow down my publish time because it has to go through all of them, correct? Sorry I forgot to mention what type/size of images I'm working with. Thanks!

Comment: Only include the pictures in the project that you need, surely you don't need *all* the 3GBs of images?

Comment: Well I have a large personnel database. Most of these pictures would be headshots... so I do kind of need these. Unless there is a way to link them I'm not thinking of. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use one of SCM's such as SVN or GIT to keep files in sync, if you don't want each time redeploy your application. But you should "checkout" to synchronize files or make a .bat file which will do that automatically.